# In LinkedIn api i am getting "Access to connections denied"

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I want to get the connections from linkedIn, but i am getting the above error, and on searching i found that i need to be registered in partner program.
So, there are 3 options available:
1. Talent
2. Marketting
3. sales

I am not sure which one to choose
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to be a partner to access 1st degree connections. You simply need to be logged in. This would be more apparent if the LinkedIn API documentation didn't require it's own documentation to navigate.

Comment: Yes, You have to take  permission from Linkedin  for partnership program. I think You have to apply for Marketting permission

Comment: @KPSingh But can you get the connections email with that?

Comment: No, You cant get any connections( 1st level or 2nd level ) email